# FX in Path Tracer in Unreal Engine 5

Tags: game-development

As I understand FX using Niagara won't be visible in Editor while using Path Tracer but as per Unreal Engine documentation it will be revealed in Movie Render Queue render.

Dynamic Scene Elements

The Path Tracer works by having the renderer accumulate samples over time. This is ideal for static scenes and less so for dynamic scenes that include elements such as moving lights, animated skinned meshes, and visual effects. These types of elements do not invalidate path tracing in the editor and appear as blurred, or streaking artifacts in the frame. This only appears when working in the editor and is remedied by using the Movie Render Queue to render out final elements.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/path-tracer-in-unreal-engine/

Does that mean FX using Niagara will be rendered using Path Tracer in Movie Render Queue?